# Aṣṭa-Akṣaram vs Pañca-Akṣaram

Tags: vaishnavism, shaivism

What does *aṣṭa-akṣaram* and *pañca-akṣaram* mean?
I guess it has do something with the Dravida (South-Indian) Vaishnavites and Saivites.

Comment: Please explain your requirement from this question? Why you have quoted a film as example here? Panchakshra is na ma si va ya mantra and ashta kshra is om namo narayana

Comment: Aṣṭa-Akṣaram Mantra is the Viśhňu Mantra: Om Namo Nârâyaňâya (ॐ नमो नारायणाय), and Pañca-Akṣaram Mantra is the Śhiva Mantra: Om Namah Śhivây (ॐ नमः शिवाय)

Comment: Thank you both for the clarification. :-)